# How do you make a set text size fill a container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking to make text with a set text-size fill a container by putting as much space between words to make the first and last words touch the ends.

Example: If there were three words / items it would have the 1st word at the far left, 2nd word in the middle and 3rd word at the far right.

[image]

I'd like to do this using css but I do not mind javascript / jquery.

Comment: Perfect use case for a `table`, imho. Set it to span `100%` width, then align the words within their `td` accordingly: 1st align left, 2nd to (n-1)th align center, nth align right.

Comment: @aefxx: see my answer below. Though I agree a table-like presentation would be best for this situation, I would *not* recommend using the `table` element, as that is for **tabular** data only. The semantics are important, too.

Comment: I am using this for links in HTML5 and looking to be semantic - I do not want to use tables. The javascript example looks promising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using some javascript so you can use it with IE7 http://jsfiddle.net/NTx2A/

Comment: This is a great method. Extremely generalizable and fool-proof... unless your visitors have JS disabled on their browsers. I'm not sure about using [`ul`s](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) for layout though... I guess it's not technically wrong, but it makes me feel weird.

Comment: this works exactly like my table example. is that JS code executed constantly in real time...? if so, then i would certainly use tables even though they arent semantically correct, but at least reduces the CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="line trio">
    <div class="unit left">One</div>
    <div class="unit mid">Two</div>
    <div class="unit right">Three</div>
</div>
<div class="line quartet">
    <div class="unit left">One</div>
    <div class="unit mid">Two</div>
    <div class="unit mid">Three</div>
    <div class="unit right">Four</div>
</div>
<div class="line duet">
    <div class="unit left">One</div>
    <div class="unit right">Two</div>
</div>
```

---

```
.line {display: table; width: 100%;}
.unit {display: table-cell;}

.duet    .unit {width: 50%;}
.trio    .unit {width: 33.3%;}
.quartet .unit {width: 25%;}

.left  {text-align: left;}
.mid   {text-align: center;}
.right {text-align: right;}
```

Comment: Feasible, but what if there happen to be 5 words next week, 7 in a month etc. I think you get the point. You would have to hard-code every possible combination.

Comment: True... but that's true for any CSS-only solution. For **true** generalization you'd need JavaScript. And with this method you could keep an external stylesheet like [this](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/blob/master/core/grid/grids.css) or [this](http://chharvey.net16.net/core/CSS/grid.css).

Answer (score 0):

Tables work pretty well here.

```
<table width="400" border="1">
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:left">one</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">two</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">three</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">four</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">five</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

no need to trick with CSS or JS, its all automatic.[image]

Comment: Though I agree a table-like presentation would be best for this situation, I would *not* recommend using the `table` element, as that is for **tabular** data only. See my answer.

Comment: Also, try to separate content from presentation. That is, inline styles are not good practice. They're quick and dirty and are great for debugging, but not a good method to stick to.

Comment: @TestSubject528491, i added style attributes just to make it compact here. i dont like your version because it requires own percents for every amount of elements there.